# how to use style defined in xaml resource dictionary?

Tags: wpf

I have a a `IMultiValueConverter` that dynamically creates `TextBlock` controls. The issue is that it has no styles.

How can I tell my new `TextBlock` to use a style that was defined in my XAML resource dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following question: [how to use DynamicResource in the code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751208/how-to-use-dynamicresource-in-the-code-behind)

Use `SetResourceReference`, it's equivalent to use `DynamicResource` in Xaml

So if your `Style` has the Key myTextBlockStyle

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.SetResourceReference(FrameworkElement.StyleProperty, "myTextBlockStyle");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried this before, and depending on what your converter is doing, I think if your XAML resource dictionary is external, then link it into the Window where you are displaying the TextBlocks:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="[the path to the resource dictionary]"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then in your textblocks, ensure they have the Style attached that is defined in the resource dictionary.  If the textblocks are being created in code behind I believe you should be able to use FindResource to locate the style that is linked in by the resource dictionary.  Then do something like this:

```
textBlock1.Style = (Style)FindResource("myTextBlockStyle");
```

Comment: I already have my resource dictionary linked like you showed. I'm trying to use a specific style (based on key) for a `TextBlock` that I dynamically create through a `IMultiValueConverter`.

Comment: I just updated my answer at the same time you commented.  Try the FindResource methods and see if it helps locate your style.  I've only embedded multivalueconverters within an element, like concatenating first and last name, I haven't used them for dynamically creating controls.